# Unable to use the transform-object-rest-spread while piping to babelify from browserify

Tags: javascript, browserify, babeljs, vuex

I'm trying to use the transform-object-rest-spread babel plugin in my gulp build pipeline.

Normally I would add this as a plugin in the .babelrc file, but this pipeline is a new addition that runs parallel to an older gulp pipeline that needs different babel options, so the plugins need to be specified in the pipeline.

This is the gulp task I have built out currently:

```
gulp.task('frontend-browserified-js', () => {
    var stream = browserify(`${files.frontendbrowserifiedjs.sourcePath}/${files.frontendbrowserifiedjs.entryPointName}`)
        .transform(vueify)
        .transform(babelify.configure({
            presets: ['es2015'],
            plugins: ["transform-runtime", "transform-object-rest-spread"]
        }))
        // .transform('babelify', {
        // })
        .bundle()
        .on('error', handleError)
        .pipe(fs.createWriteStream(`${files.frontendbrowserifiedjs.dest}/${files.frontendbrowserifiedjs.bundleName}`))

    function handleError(error) {
        console.error(error.stack)
        console.log(chalk.red('hit error while gulping.'))
    }
})
```

From the pipeline above:

```
presets: ['es2015'], // this preset _does_ work
plugins: ["transform-runtime", "transform-object-rest-spread"] // but these plugins are not recognized as far as I can tell
```

I keep hitting the following error while gulping:
[image: error message]

Is there a correct way to pass in the plugins for a specific pipeline like this?